# how to stop setinterval by using mouse wheel or using touchscroll on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I've been facing regarding the functionality of the `setInterval` function. Specifically, I have been struggling to disable the execution of the `setInterval` function when the user engages in scrolling, either by using the mouse scroll wheel or by scrolling upwards on a mobile device screen.

Even when I attempt to use `clearInterval` within the `window.addEventListener('wheel')` function, I have been unable to achieve the desired outcome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="start-scrolling" style="position: fixed;">start scrolling after stopping</button>
  <div class="container" style="overflow: auto;">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: aqua;">
      <h1>ghnghgh</h1>
      <h1>ghnghgh</h1>
      <h1>ghnghgh</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: rgb(132, 0, 255);"></div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: rgb(132, 0, 255);"></div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: rgb(132, 0, 255);"></div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var isScrollingEnabled = true;
var isScrolling = false;
var x = 1;
var scrollAnimation;
var myInterval = setInterval(scrollChatToBottom, 100); // تعيين الفاصل الزمني الأول

function scrollChatToBottom() {
  if (isScrollingEnabled && !isScrolling) {
    scrollAnimation = $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".container")[0].scrollHeight }, 2000);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
  $("html, body").stop();
console.log("stop");
clearInterval(scrollAnimation)
});

$(document.body).on('touchmove',  function(event){
  $("html, body").stop();
console.log("stop");
clearInterval(scrollAnimation)
   });



      setTimeout(function() {
    startTyping();
    $('.container').append(
          '<div class="left-msg msg left-msg">' +
          '<div class="msg-bubble">' +
          '<div class="msg-info">' +
          '<div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(\'https://apt.nafistech.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/NafisLogo.png\')"></div>' +
          '<div class="msg-info-name">Nafis Tech</div>' +
          '<p class="cht-name">Bot</p>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="">' +
          '<div class="text-js11">' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="show-text-typing-here11 left-msg msg-text"></div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="suggesions suggesions1" style="display:none;">' +
          '<button class="sugg_btn Solutions" style="padding-left: 30px !important;padding-right: 30px !important;"> Solutions  <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></button>' +
          '<button class="sugg_btn Pricing" style="padding-left: 30px !important;padding-right: 30px !important;"> Pricing  <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right</i></button>' +
          '<button class="sugg_btn Contact" style="padding-left: 30px !important;padding-right: 30px !important;"> Contact  <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></button>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>'
        );
        
      }, 1000);

      setTimeout(function() {
        startTyping();
  }, 1000);
     

      function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      }

      async function typeWriter(textElement, text, delay) {
        const lines = text.split('<p class="line-break">');
          console.log('111111111');
        for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
          const line = lines[i].replace('</p>', '');
          console.log('2222222');

          for (let j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
            await sleep(delay);
            textElement.innerHTML += line.charAt(j);

          }
          console.log('4444444');

          if (i > 0) {
            textElement.innerHTML += '<br>';
            console.log('555555');

          }
          console.log('66666');

          
        }
        console.log('7777777');

      }

      async function startTyping() {
        const textElement = document.querySelector('.text-js11');
        const textToShowElement = document.querySelector('.show-text-typing-here11');
        const text = textElement.innerHTML.trim();

        textElement.style.display = 'none';
        await typeWriter(textToShowElement, text, 30);

        $(".suggesions1").css("display", "block");
      }
  //     setTimeout(function() {
  //       scrollChatToBottom();
  // }, 100);

    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make sure that setintrval execution stops working

Thank you very much for your help, as I have tried in various ways, but I cannot find a satisfactory solution

Comment: The variable you are using to reference the timer is: `var myInterval = setInterval(scr...`, but the variable you are using with `clearInterval` is `scrollAnimation`.

Answer (score 0):

Your interval timer variable is: `myInterval`, but you are calling `clearInterval(scrollAnimation)`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="start-scrolling" style="position: fixed;">start scrolling after stopping</button>
  <div class="container" style="overflow: auto;">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: aqua;">
      <h1>ghnghgh</h1>
      <h1>ghnghgh</h1>
      <h1>ghnghgh</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: rgb(132, 0, 255);"></div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: rgb(132, 0, 255);"></div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: rgb(132, 0, 255);"></div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var isScrollingEnabled = true;
      var isScrolling = false;
      var x = 1;
      var scrollAnimation;
      var myInterval = setInterval(scrollChatToBottom, 100); // تعيين الفاصل الزمني الأول

      function scrollChatToBottom() {
        if (isScrollingEnabled && !isScrolling) {
          scrollAnimation = $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".container")[0].scrollHeight }, 2000);
        }
      }

window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
  $("html, body").stop();
  console.log("stop");
  clearInterval(myInterval);  // <-- You must reference the timer variable
});

$(document.body).on('touchmove',  function(event){
  $("html, body").stop();
  console.log("stop");
  clearInterval(myInterval);  // <-- You must reference the timer variable
});



      setTimeout(function() {
    startTyping();
    $('.container').append(
          '<div class="left-msg msg left-msg">' +
          '<div class="msg-bubble">' +
          '<div class="msg-info">' +
          '<div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(\'https://apt.nafistech.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/NafisLogo.png\')"></div>' +
          '<div class="msg-info-name">Nafis Tech</div>' +
          '<p class="cht-name">Bot</p>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="">' +
          '<div class="text-js11">' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '<p class="line-break">Hello there!  </p>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="show-text-typing-here11 left-msg msg-text"></div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="suggesions suggesions1" style="display:none;">' +
          '<button class="sugg_btn Solutions" style="padding-left: 30px !important;padding-right: 30px !important;"> Solutions  <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></button>' +
          '<button class="sugg_btn Pricing" style="padding-left: 30px !important;padding-right: 30px !important;"> Pricing  <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right</i></button>' +
          '<button class="sugg_btn Contact" style="padding-left: 30px !important;padding-right: 30px !important;"> Contact  <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></button>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>'
        );
        
      }, 1000);

      setTimeout(function() {
        startTyping();
  }, 1000);
     

      function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      }

      async function typeWriter(textElement, text, delay) {
        const lines = text.split('<p class="line-break">');
          console.log('111111111');
        for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
          const line = lines[i].replace('</p>', '');
          console.log('2222222');

          for (let j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
            await sleep(delay);
            textElement.innerHTML += line.charAt(j);

          }
          console.log('4444444');

          if (i > 0) {
            textElement.innerHTML += '<br>';
            console.log('555555');

          }
          console.log('66666');

          
        }
        console.log('7777777');

      }

      async function startTyping() {
        const textElement = document.querySelector('.text-js11');
        const textToShowElement = document.querySelector('.show-text-typing-here11');
        const text = textElement.innerHTML.trim();

        textElement.style.display = 'none';
        await typeWriter(textToShowElement, text, 30);

        $(".suggesions1").css("display", "block");
      }
  //     setTimeout(function() {
  //       scrollChatToBottom();
  // }, 100);

    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**strong text**